# When using Pinia and TypeScript how do you use an Action to set the State?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Pinia + TypeScript store named `user.ts` that looks like this:

```
import { User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () =>
    ({
      displayName: null,
      email: null,
      emailVerified: null,
      isAnonymous: null,
      metadata: null,
      multiFactor: null,
      phoneNumber: null,
      photoURL: null,
      providerData: null,
      providerId: null,
      refreshToken: null,
      tenantId: null,
      uid: null,
    } as unknown as User),
  actions: {
    setPhotoURL(photoURLData: string | null) {
      this.photoURL = photoURLData; //<-- ERROR HERE
    },
  },
});
```

The state is a FireBase User object.

And I want to update `photoURL` using the `setPhotoURL()` action.

But `photoURL` has this TypeScript error:

```
Cannot assign to 'photoURL' because it is a read-only property. ts(2540)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is this the correct way to update state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `readonly` modifier by [mapping the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) :

> #### Mapping Modifiers
>
> There are two additional modifiers which can be applied during mapping: `readonly` and `?` which affect mutability and optionality respectively.
>
> You can remove or add these modifiers by prefixing with `-` or `+`. If you don’t add a prefix, then `+` is assumed.
>
> ```js
> // Removes 'readonly' attributes from a type's properties
> type CreateMutable<Type> = {
>   -readonly [Property in keyof Type]: Type[Property];
> };
> ```

If the type has nested properties that you want to be writeable, map recursively:

```js
type CreateMutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: CreateMutable<T[P]> }
```

Then use it to type the store's `user` property:

```js
import type { User } from 'firebase/auth'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

type CreateMutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: CreateMutable<T[P]> }

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({ user: {} as CreateMutable<User> }),

  actions: {
    setPhotoURL(photoURLData: string | null) {
      this.user.photoURL = photoURLData
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`'firebase/auth'` declares User interface as having `readonly` props. When you forcefully apply that interface to your state object, TS trusts you.

Spreading it should remove the `readonly` from its props, while still inferring the types:

```
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({ ...({
    displayName: null,
    email: null,
    emailVerified: null,
    isAnonymous: null,
    metadata: null,
    multiFactor: null,
    phoneNumber: null,
    photoURL: null,
    providerData: null,
    providerId: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    tenantId: null,
    uid: null,
  } as unknown as User) }),
  actions: {
    //...
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks this wroked! But to simplify things I have decided to change my state to this `state: () => ({ user: null as unknown as User, }),`. The `user` property will then hold everything returned by Firebase. Given that change, how do implement the spread? I have tried quite a few variations but can't get it working.

Comment: You seem to think you'll be able to get a user from firebase and change its props. You won't. The reason why those fields are marked `readonly` is because trying to write to them will result in an error. Obviously, you can make a copy of it and change that. But to update a user's photo you should simply call firebase's API to change it in db and get back the modified user. Anyways, if what you want is a *"writtable"* User in your state, here's how to do it: 
`type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] }`. And `state: () => ({ user<null | Writeable<User>>: null })`

Comment: But telling TS your user is writable won't actually make the JS object returned by firebase writable. You'll still get an error. The error TS is trying to warn you about.